# Products of sums of $2n$ squares

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

It is well-known that the product of two squares is a square, and the product of sums of two squares is a sum of two squares (Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity):
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$$
and an analogous result holds for sums of four squares ([Euler's four square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity)), eight squares ([Degen's eight square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degen%27s_eight-square_identity)) and 16 squares ([Pfister's 16 square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfister%27s_sixteen-square_identity)).

According to the Wikipedia article, analogous results hold for all sums of $2^n$ squares. But what about sums of $2n$ squares? Is it known whether there is a formula for the product of sums of 6 squares as a sum of 6 squares, i.e. whether, given $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^6a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^6b_j^2\right)=\sum_{k=1}^6c_k^2$$
where $c_k=f_k(a_1,\ldots,a_6,b_1,\ldots,b_6)$ for some polynomials $f_k$?

Comment: This is trivially true, since every non-negative integer is the sum of six squares. But there is no such formula as for powers of two.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, so doesn't this mean it's trivial for every sum of $\ge 4$ squares? What is the significance of the 8 and 16 square identities?

Comment: There are no nice formulas, but do such formulas exist?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Wikipedia certainly would have mentioned those, right? K. Conrad's article is cited for $m=16$, there should be an argument given there, why we should have $m=2^n$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I found it in Conrad's article. It is called "A Converse to Pfister's Theorem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such formula.

Pfister’s theorem tells us that in any field, when $n$ is a power of 2, the set of sums of $n$ squares is closed under multiplication. It follows that when $n$ is a power of 2, there is a formula for the $c_k$ in terms of $a_i,b_i$, where $(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2)(b_1^2+\ldots+b_n^2)=c_1^2+\ldots+c_n^2$ .

Another theorem of Pfister (converse of Pfister’s above theorem) tells us that for every positive integer $n$ that is not a power of 2, the nonzero sums of $n$ squares are not closed under multiplication in the field $\mathbb{R}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. This means that there are two sums of $n$ squares in this field such that their product is not a sum of $n$ squares in the field. Hence no formula exists when $n$ is not a power of 2.

Source: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/pfister.pdf